# Get PayPal transaction details by transaction number REST

Tags: paypal

customers have a `transaction number` to identify their purchases. When they have a problem with the transaction, they tell us this `transaction number`. They do not have any further number.

-> This is **NOT** the `paymentId` / `saleId` / `orderId`.

Looking at the [PayPal REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/), I can not find any call to get details of the transaction providing the `transaction number`. I'd like to get the `paymentId` (PAY-XXXXXXXXXXX) or `invoice number`.

The transaction is made with the Android SDK.

**Question**: How do we get the `paymentId` (PAY-XXXXXXXXXXX) from the `transaction number` using the REST API?

Thank you!